# Rails model validation with multi page wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where the data is entered over 2 pages. I would like to validate the fields entered on the first page however it isn't until the second page that the whole model can possibly be valid.

I want to use the standard Rails validation presentation (highlight the fields in error, display the message at the top, reload the page with all the data already in the fields). I would like to avoid coding the validation in the controller.

Has anyone seen a better approach than using the controller, or creating a new "dummy" model with just the data from the first page (which is never saved in the DB).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an excellent Railscast on this topic. Hopefully you will find useful.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to your validation, here is an abstract of one of my apps:

```
validates_presence_of :years_expertise, :if => lambda { |object| object.current_step == "5" || account_active == true}
```